# Add views to the right or under depeneding on size of view

Tags: java, android

Basically, I have a bunch of custom TextViews and a set of data. I programatically inflate the textviews and set their texts according to my data. I want to add my views to the right of each other, and when there is no room horizontally, it will add a new row below. However, I am not sure what layout/view to use to achieve my goal.

Example of what I am trying to achieve:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fzzzK.jpg)

Please Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the [Flexbox Layout library](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) from Google. It does exactly this for you.